# unrecognized modifier `_bsontype` in sails v1

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I am trying to upgrade my sails.js application from v0.12 to v1. The following query is not working anymore after upgrade.

```
return Passport.findOne({
    protocol: 'local',
    user: user.id // also tested user instead of user.id
  })
```

I am getting the following error:

```
{ UsageError: Invalid criteria.
   Details:
     Could not use the provided `where` clause.  Could not filter by `user`: Unrecognized modifier (`_bsontype`) within provided constraint for `user`.
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help regarding this.

Comment: did you find any answer to this?

Comment: @ShashanSooriyahetti nope, skipped the migration due to issues. It wasn't worth of effort for us.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the findOne does not like the _bsontype property instead should be a plain string

this will not work

```
// Fetch the user associated with the Passport
return User.findOne({ id: passport.user });
```

but this will work fine

```
// Fetch the user associated with the Passport
return User.findOne({ id: passport.user + '' });
```